# Replacing i th column name with the i-1 th column name for a whole data set in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am a new R user. I am trying to replace every i th column's name with it's preceded column's (i-1 th) name for the whole data set.
I have 96 columns in my data set.
the following for loop is not working.

```
for (i in dat[2:96]){
names(dat)[i]<-paste(names(dat)[i-1])
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What happens to the first column name?

Comment: To make a better question, instead of dat use one of the example data sets such as `iris` and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your task there is no need to use a loop, you can use a vectorized approach instead. In R you should always look out for options to vectorize your code, since this is more concise and faster than loops. This does not mean that loops are not good per se, you should just check if you can use a simpler approach.

For your case you can use an index-based replacement of the names as shown below.

```
# use the R internal mtcars as exemplary data
dat = mtcars
# replace colnames by index
colnames(dat)[2:ncol(dat)] = colnames(dat)[1:(ncol(dat)-1)]
# compare the results to the original data
colnames(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
colnames(dat)
# [1] "mpg"  "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
```

Answer (score 1):

No loop necessary.

```
names(dat) <- c("firstcol", names(dat)[1:95])
```

This also changes the name of the first column to "firstcol" to avoid having two columns of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This works without loop and without changing the first column's name.

```
library(rlang)
set_names(dat, nm = c(colnames(dat[1]), colnames(dat[1:95])))
```

Comment: Of course you don't HAVE to change the first column's name. I did that deliberately, because having two columns with the same name is a bad idea.